# Location for connectionstring when dealing with application updates

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, connection-string

One of the applications i'm developing is in use by various clients. The application needs to connect to a database and therefore has a connectionstring defined in the app.config. Each client however needs a different connectionstring.

The client must provide the database information during the installation of the product. With each new release they need provide this information.

What I actually want is that some setting, like the connectionstring, are stored in a location that isn't affected by a new installation. What is the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: Using the registry is an option.

Comment: I think that this is a wrong approach to the general problem of updating an already installed application. Your setup program should be able to identify a previous installation and do not overwrite or remove any of the previous data still needed by the new release

Comment: That is exactly what i used to think. But when I change something to the app.config, no matter what, the installer needs to update the app.config.

Comment: Is it a bad practice to store the connectionstring in a settings file that is managed by the application? The software upon launch searches for the info it needs. if it doesn't find them, it starts questioning the user and stores the information in a file that will not be deleted by the installer/uninstaller?

Comment: I ended up using "<connectionstrings configsource=". The first install is done by me and I will make de connectionstrings.config file. This file will not be deleted by de uninstaller. Now the clients can perform the updates without specifying the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a transform (http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/transforms) for each client?  Stick the connection string in a property, and use a transform to update it on the client, it'll be a lot quicker/easier than updating the installer to use something they enter during the install (and possible less error prone).  Simple as running:

> installer.msi transforms=client.mst

The downside is they then have to ensure they use the transform when they run the installer, now sure how you package these things up or launch them etc.  If it's something you just give to any old Tom, Dick or Harry this might not be the best solution, if it's you or someone you know installing it, then it could be an easy solution.

Alternatively, you could use a DSN or something setup on the machine to keep them consistent.

Otherwise you've got to modify/edit your installation, in which case you should take a look at http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the connection string in the registry, you can retrieve and store the value as a property when doing an upgrade by searching for the value.  If the value isn't found you can treat as a clean install and prompt for the value, or retrieve it as a command line property.

Searching can be achieved using [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) here's an example:

```
<Property Id="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING">
  <RegistrySearch Id="DbConnectionString" Root="HKLM" Key="MyDBConnectionStringLocation" Name="ConnectionString" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

To store the value use the [RegsitryValue](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registryvalue.htm) element:

```
<Component Id="PersistentProperty" KeyPath="yes">
  <RegistryValue Id="DbConnectionString" Root="HKLM" Key="MyDBConnectionStringLocation" Value="[DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING]" Name="DbConnectionString" Type="string" />
</Component>
```